# An alternative for "CSharpCodeProvider.Parse"

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm looking for an alternative for `CSharpCodeProvider.Parse`. The method was supposed to parse a [C#] code source and return a `CompileUnit` object. However, the method isn't implemented in any .Net framework.

My purpose is to be able to navigate a C# CodeDOM without having to compile it. I'm writing a application that does some code analysis but I won't necessarily have all external references, which means I can't compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpDevelop (the open source IDE commonly used for Mono) has a library called NRefactory that allows you to parse C# code and convert it into an AST:  http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/NRefactory.ashx  (Excerpt from that link follows):

```
using (IParser parser = ParserFactory.CreateParser(SupportedLanguage.CSharp, new StringReader(sourceCode))) 
{
    parser.Parse();
    // this allows retrieving comments, preprocessor directives, etc. (stuff that isn't part of the syntax)
    specials = parser.Lexer.SpecialTracker.RetrieveSpecials();
    // this retrieves the root node of the result AST
    result = parser.CompilationUnit;
    if (parser.Errors.Count > 0) {
        MessageBox.Show(parser.Errors.ErrorOutput, "Parse errors");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many [free C# parsers](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+parser), the most popular apparently being:

- [CsParser](http://csparser.codeplex.com/) (on CodePlex)

Answer (score 0):

Actual (2017-2018) info:

1. More info available at https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/NRefactory
2. Download nuget package: "ICSharpCode.NRefactory"
3. And here is code snippet:

   ```
   using ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   namespace Ns1
   {
       public class Foo
       {
           public void Go()
           {       
               CSharpParser parser = new CSharpParser();
               string text = File.ReadAllText("myProgram.cs");
               SyntaxTree syntaxTree = parser.Parse(text);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a tool for building analysis tools for arbitrary languages.
DMS provides generalized parsing, AST navigation and modification, regeneration of source from a modified tree, symbol table support, and various kinds of analysis support as well as the ability to write source-to-source transformations that modify the ASTs directly in terms of surface syntax.

Its [C# Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CSharpFrontEnd.html) provides a full C# 4.0 parser (including LINQ) that builds a full abstract syntax tree containing every item of the source text, including comments captured as annotations on source tree nodes that the comments decorate.