# In C#, what is a good way to exclude a class when outputting code from textfile

Tags: c#, string

What I want to do may seem like a weird scenario. Please keep in mind that I need to do this for a Demo project, where I output c# code to the user to teach them how certain controls are coded.

I am given a .cs file and I need to output the contents. There is at least one class in the file, and at most...a lot. I need to output the whole file, EXCEPT one type of class. The specific type of class that I want to prevent being outputted all inherit a certain base class, so they should be easy to distinguish.

Here is an example:

```
    public abstract class A{}

    public class B{]

    public class C{}
```

Assume these are the base-types that some of my classes may inherit. I want to prevent outputting all classes that inherit from A. A is probably going to be the only abstract base class so if that can help in anyway, that would be awesome.

Let's say I'm given a file, example.cs:

```
    using System;
    using OtherStuff;

    namespace blah.blahagain.someotherblah
    {
      [AttributeOne]
      [AttributeTwo]
      [AttributeThree]
      public class AA: A
      {
        //stuff
      }

      public class BB: B
      {
        //stuff
      }

      public class CC: C
      {
        //stuff
      }

      public class D
      {
        //stuff
      }

    }
```

And the output should be

```
    using System;
    using OtherStuff;

    namespace blah.blahagain.someotherblah
    {
      public class BB: B
      {
        //stuff
      }

      public class CC: C
      {
        //stuff
      }

      public class D
      {
        //stuff
      }

    }
```

The only way I have thought of is brute-force string manipulation. I can't, however, use whitespace as a separator between classes because there is no guarantee if there will even be white space between classes. I will need to keep track of open and closed curly brackets to discover where one class begins and another end. I also need to test for the base class of each class by testing the string tokens before the first {} pair.

Also I need to prevent the attributes of AA from outputted too.

Since there are many brighter minds out there, I am here to ask if there is another simpler/cleaner method for doing what I need.

Thanks for reading!

Edit after YetAnotherUser's answer: The output should be exactly the same as the file, which includes all comments.

Another edit: Instead of answering with certain software or libraries that could do this, I would more prefer algorithms. Maybe regular expressions? I am not good with them so I do not know the extend that they can be used for.

Comment: Are there any guarantees about the format of that code file at all? Such as all matching { and } braces are at the same level? ie. could you find the indentation for "public class" and then skip to the matching }, or can you risk having classes like the ones in your first code-example, ie. everything on one line?

Comment: The guideline for coding has specifications about indentation but there's no guarantee the files will be correctly indented (people get lazy)

Comment: Why do you need to output a second file from this? Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: What do you mean by second file? I just need to output the file to screen, excluding one class.

Comment: Ok, sorry, why do you need to do that then? Can't you use a predefined file instead, so that you know exactly what's in it?

Comment: Basically I want to exclude the class that may confuse the user (it wasn't my idea to exclude the class though). I don't make the files, that's the problem. I could tell the coder to split the file into two then just display the one I need, but that's a lot of files and a lot of work for the coder. I want to do more work in the back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you wrap everything you need to exclude with:

```
#region ExcludeRegion
  [AttributeOne]
  [AttributeTwo]
  [AttributeThree]
  public class AA: A
  {
    //stuff
  }
#endregion
```

See the [#region documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28VS.71%29.aspx)

This should be relatively easy to scan for and exclude.  It also gives you the added benefit of showing what you're hiding in the IDE.

Comment: It sounds like the OP doesn't have much control over the input file though.

Comment: People add more files to the project as they please. It's an internal helper product and all developers have access. If I have to request everyone to wrap it I think it'll be inconvenient. I already redesigned the project to make it less dependent on things that MUST be done for it to work properly. And also as an fyi we've been using regions inside the code already.

Comment: If that is the only solution then I may try it. But it's a trade off: less work discovering what to hide and more work for the developers who code the files. But I'd rather do more work behind the scenes than depend on the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use open-source lib [NRefactory](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/NRefactory.ashx). It supports parsing the code into AST which you can modify afterwards and generate output code. It also can retain your comments as shown on their wiki page.

Found it here: [An alternative for "CSharpCodeProvider.Parse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631909/an-alternative-for-csharpcodeprovider-parse)

Comment: Is this a third-party library? The problem is that the Demo will be attached to an actual product that will be shipped. Even though the Demo should not appear in the Release version, we still try not to use third party code. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: I could write my own parser that it similar to your suggestion though, which goes back to my original string-manipulation idea.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Yufei - "brute-force" string manipulation is not same as parsing.

Comment: Oh you're right. Sorry I just meant that it would require me to work through the file as a string.***

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Apparently there's no implementation of CodeDomProvider that supports parsing. Hence this is invalid - I'll keep this post to ensure this is highlighted to someone thinking on same lines.

---

<strike>You can parse the code using [CodeDomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.parse%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and then remove the required classes and regenerate the code file.</strike>

If it is for educational purpose, this might not exactly fit your needs as generated file might not exactly match with the original source file.

See -

1. [System.CodeDom Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx)
2. [Using the CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)
3. [Microsoft .NET CodeDom Technology - Part 1](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020917.htm)

Comment: The trouble is that CSharpCodeProvider apparently doesn't support the Parse method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631909/an-alternative-for-csharpcodeprovider-parse

Comment: @AlexD - great catch, Never used it but always assumed it does. I'll just try it out and update my answer.

Comment: I edited my post to add that I need to retain comments as well. I read through the links and it seems you can use that to regenerate code it saves in a CodeCompileUnit, but I'm not sure if it'll save comments as well.

Comment: Yep, I wanted to give the same answer to yours.. Then checked it quickly and found this problem.